# Set installation for Windows 10 to specify drive letter and path without spaces

Tags: windows, installation, nsis, cpack

I am trying to create a Windows installer using CPACK and NSIS. I am using Windows 10, CMake GUI, NSIS, and Visual Studio Community Edition.

It works great except that I can't find the options so that the default install location will be:

```
 C:\package-version.patch (e.g. C:\apbs-3.0)
```

The apbs software is a collaboration effort and is cross platform but it does not like "spaces" in pathnames so the default location for NSIS on Windows 10 x64 is:

```
 C:\Program Files\package version (e.g. C:\Program Files\apbs 3.0\)
```

The closest I have gotten to is:

```
 C:\\apbs 3.0
```

using the following configuration:

```
    string(TOLOWER ${PROJECT_NAME}         PACKAGE_NAME)
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME                 "${PACKAGE_NAME}")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION          "${PACKAGE_DESC}")
    set(CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_LICENSE        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../LICENSE.md")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_FILE     "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/README.md")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX     "${PACKAGE_NAME}")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION              "${APBS_VERSION}")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH        "0")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR               "${VENDOR}")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_CONTACT              "${CONTACT}")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME            "${PACKAGE_NAME}-${APBS_VERSION}")
    set(CPACK_STRIP_FILES                  ON)
    if(WIN32)
        # From: https://martinrotter.github.io/it-programming/2014/05/09/integrating-nsis-cmake/
        list(APPEND CPACK_GENERATOR              "NSIS")
        set(CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX       "\\\\${PACKAGE_NAME}-${APBS_VERSION}")
        set(CPACK_NSIS_INSTALL_ROOT              "C:\\\\")
    endif()

    include (CPack)
```

Is there a magic/undocumented set of CPACK variables to eliminate the extra '\' and replace the "space" with a '-' so that I can get the default install to be?

```
 C:\apbs-3.0\
```

Answer (score 0):

The following got me the install directory, C:\APBS-3.0.0

```
set(CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION "3")
set(CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION "0")
set(CMAKE_MICRO_VERSION "0")
set(PACKAGE_NAME                       "${PROJECT_NAME}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME                 "${PACKAGE_NAME}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION          "APBS - Adaptive Poisson Boltzmann Solver")
set(CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_LICENSE        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../LICENSE.md")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_FILE     "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/README.md")
set(CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES          "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR};/.git/;.gitignore")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR        "${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR        "${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH        "${CMAKE_MICRO_VERSION}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR               "PNNL")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_CONTACT              "APBS - https://github.com/Electrostatics/apbs-pdb2pqr")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME            "${PACKAGE_NAME}-${APBS_VERSION}")
set(CPACK_STRIP_FILES                   ON)

if(WIN32)
    # From: https://martinrotter.github.io/it-programming/2014/05/09/integrating-nsis-cmake/
    SET(CPACK_NSIS_PACKAGE_NAME              "${PACKAGE_NAME}-${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_MICRO_VERSION}")
    SET(CPACK_NSIS_DISPLAY_NAME              "${PACKAGE_NAME}-${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_MICRO_VERSION}")
    SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY      "${PACKAGE_NAME}-${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_MICRO_VERSION}")
    SET(CPACK_NSIS_INSTALL_ROOT              "C:")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY   "${PACKAGE_NAME}-${MAJOR_VERSION}.${MINOR_VERSION}.${MICRO_VERSION}")
    list(APPEND CPACK_GENERATOR              "NSIS")
endif()
```

Hopefully this can help others looking for similar solutions.